# JBoss EAP 5 leaves a lot of TCP connections open in CLOSE_WAIT status. How can this be traced in logs?

Tags: java, jboss, threadpool, jboss5.x

So I see a lot of TCP connections being left open in CLOSE_WAIT status from our application, running on JBoss EAP 5. This happens only in one test environment, all other environments are fine. The end result is that the JVM crashes due to not enough memory.

I need to trace where in the application the threads are being left open. How can I debug this? Can I configure this in jboss-log4j.xml?

Comment: You can show the output of the following command  `lsof -i | grep CLOSE_WAIT` and `netstat -n | grep CLOSE_WAIT`

Comment: I have used the netstat -command, and verified that a lot of connections are open. However, I would need loks from JBoss exactly when/where the connections are left open. Possible to do this in JBoss?

Comment: what are the ports that are used by these sockets?

Comment: They are varying and look like random RMI ports? Examples are 54587, 54584, 54585, etc. ...

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/GenerateAThreadDumpUsingJMXConsoleJBossAS3456